# Google API insight raw numbers

Tags: country, insight

I was wondering if there is an option in google Insights (or in any other Google API) to query how many times a specific word or phrase has been queried in Google, grouped by Country, State and City.

The problems with Google Insights is that it give me only an average information, and not the exact amount, so it ends up not showing all the cities.

Look here:
http://www.google.com/insights/search/#q=pizza&geo=AU-NSW&date=1%2F2004%2085m&cmpt=q

Querying all terms "pizza" was searched from 2004 until 2011 in the country Australia and state New South Wales.
It shows up only "Sydney", what is definitely wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks..

Diego Trigo

Answer (score 0):

No. Although many claims to be but there is no service that can tell you the exact number of a query searched in Google nor in any other search engine.

You can also try Google trends as an add to information.

Comment: Thanks Stephen... actually google trends provides even less information than insights... Thank you for your reply anyway.